# Preg_matching content in PHP quick question!

Tags: php

I want to get the content of these:

```
<div class="scene_box">
WHATEVER IS IN HERE
<div class="clear"></div>
```

But I cant get the content inbetween

This is my code:

```
preg_match("/<div class=\"scene_box\">(.*?)<div class=\"clear\"><\/div>
```

`<\/div> /", $res, $match);`

if anyone can help it would be much appreciated

theres multiple of the scene_box so thats why I am using  preg_match

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse HTML with regular expressions. Use something like [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You already got a better advise with the other answer (which should be a comment however). To extend that with an useful example, this is how extremely easily you could utilize phpQuery or QueryPath for your case:

```
print qp($html)->find("div.scene_box")->text();
```

But to also answer your actual regex question, you forgot the `/s` modifier at the end of your regex. This is why the `(.*?)` won't match the content in between the markers/tags. The `.` dot usually ignores line-breaks / CRLF.